# Laravel: Model-Form Binding undefined variable

Tags: php, laravel-5

Saudações, sou novo a usar o laravel, e neste momento uso laravel 5.3,não consigo editar qualquer dado na minha database e estou usando Route Model Binding. O erro que me dá é "**undefined variable $senhor_encontrado**" do objecto que passei por uma view.

O meu roteamento:

```
Route::get('admin/procurarPaciente','AdminController@procurar_paciente');
Route::put('admin/editarPaciente','AdminController@editar_paciente');
```

Os meus controllers:

```
   class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
    public function procurar_paciente(Request $request){
    $id_pessoa=Auth::user()->id_pessoa;
    $pessoa=Pessoa::find($id_pessoa);
    $nome_pessoa=$pessoa->nome_pessoa;
    $encontrado=false;
    $senhor_encontrado=false;
    $nome_paciente=$request->get('nome_paciente');

    $pacientes=Pessoa::all();
        foreach($pacientes as $paciente){
            if($nome_paciente == $paciente->nome_pessoa){
                $encontrado=true;
                $senhor_encontrado=$paciente;
            }
        }


     if(!$encontrado){
         Session::flash('flash_message_paciente_error','Desculpe, mas o paciente não foi encontrado!');
         return view('sessoes.administrador')->with('nome_pessoa',$nome_pessoa);
     }else{
         return View::make('editar.paciente',compact('nome_pessoa','senhor_encontrado'));
     }
}
```

O metodo **procurar_paciente** funciona e visualiza os dados no formulario, mas quando submete os dados para editar a variável 
**$senhor_encontrado** não é mais reconhecida, o código do formulário:

```
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="seccoes burner-light-blue">Editar um Paciente</h1>
    <hr><br>
    {!! Form::model($senhor_encontrado,array('url' =>'admin/editarPaciente','data-parsley-validate' => '','class' => 'burner-form' ,'method' =>'PUT')) !!}

     <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
      <div class="form-group">
         {{  Form::label('name','Nome:')}}
         {{ Form::text('nome_pessoa',null,array(
                                                 'data-parsley-required' => 'true',
                                                  'class' =>'form-control',
                                                  'aria-describedby' => 'nome',
                                                  'placeholder'=>'Escreva o Nome do Paciente',
                                                  'data-parsley-length'=>'[3, 15]',

                                               )

         ) }}
     </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{  Form::label('name','Email:')}}
        {{ Form::text('email',null,array(
                                         'data-parsley-required' => 'true',
                                          'class' =>'form-control',
                                          'placeholder'=>'Escreva o Email do Paciente',
                                           'data-parsley-type'=>'email',
                                         )

        ) }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{  Form::label('name','Palavra-Passe:')}}
        {{ Form::password('password',array(
                                          'data-parsley-required' => 'true',
                                          'class' =>'form-control',
                                          'placeholder'=>'Escreva a Palavra-Passe do Paciente',
                                           'data-parsley-length'=>'[6, 20]',
                                           'id' => 'passwordPaciente',
                                         )

        )}}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('name','Confirmar Palavra-Passe:')}}
        {{ Form::password('password-confirm',array(
                                           'data-parsley-required' => 'true',
                                           'type' => 'password',
                                           'class' =>'form-control',
                                           'placeholder'=>'Escreva novamente a Palavra-Passe do Paciente',
                                           'data-parsley-length'=>'[6, 20]',
                                           'data-parsley-equalto' =>'#passwordPaciente',
                                         )

        )}}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{  Form::label('name','Morada:')}}
        {{ Form::text('morada',null,array(
                                                'data-parsley-required' => 'true',
                                                 'class' =>'form-control',
                                                 'aria-describedby' => 'morada',
                                                 'placeholder'=>'Avenida/Rua',
                                                 'data-parsley-length'=>'[3, 40]',
                                            )

        ) }}



{!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
```

Espero que me ajudem. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente que isso aí está bem complexo de entender, vamos partir do princípio que quando você precisa de um foreach para procurar algum dado no seu banco de dados, é muita certeza de ter algo errado, não que não vá funcionar, mas isso pode sobrecarregar os servidor com interações não necessárias.

Assim, seu controlador deveria ser algo como:

```
class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
    public function procurar_paciente(Request $request){
    $id_pessoa=Auth::user()->id_pessoa;
    $pessoa=Pessoa::find($id_pessoa);
    $nome_pessoa=$pessoa->nome_pessoa;
    $encontrado=false;
    $senhor_encontrado=false;
    $nome_paciente=$request->get('nome_paciente');

    $senhor_encontrado = Pessoa::select('*')->where('nome_pessoa', '=', $nome_paciente)->get(1);



     if($senhor_encontrado->count() == 0){
         Session::flash('flash_message_paciente_error','Desculpe, mas o paciente não foi encontrado!');
         return view('sessoes.administrador')->with('nome_pessoa',$nome_pessoa);
     }else{
         return View::make('editar.paciente',compact('nome_pessoa','senhor_encontrado'));
     }
}
```

A modificação que fiz aqui, pode ser conferida aqui:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#selects

Além do mais, com o `foreach`, você não passa o objeto todo do retorno, apenas a parte com o array associativo, e é um pouco difícil de afirmar, mas pode ser esse o problema.

Comment: Obrigado @Gabriel. Vou alterar o meu código.